# sudo npm install -g cordova ionic - not working, because EEXIST

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova, ionic-framework, terminal

Hi i wanted to install ionic with the following command and got Errno 17.

```
    npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic
npm ERR! dest /Users/christopherwippel/.npm-global/bin/ionic
npm ERR! errno -17
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic' -> '/Users/christopherwippel/.npm-global/bin/ionic'
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/christopherwippel/.npm-global/bin/ionic
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/christopherwippel/.npm/_logs/2020-02-07T18_44_53_116Z-debug.log
christophersMBP:Desktop christopherwippel$
```

Does anybody know what the problem is and how i could solve it?

Thanks, if you need any additional information just let me know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ionic have changed their cli installation command.

New command is:
`npm install -g @ionic/cli`

P.S: https://ionicframework.com/blog/a-new-package-for-the-cli/

Comment: Yes you can add cordova if you want to. otherwise you can install them separately. E.g: `npm install -g @ionic/cli cordova` or `npm install -g cordova` separately.

Answer (score 4):

You have to uninstall first

```
$ npm uninstall -g ionic
$ npm install -g @ionic/cli
```

As mentioned in the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/blog/a-new-package-for-the-cli/)